# How can I get JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode to serialize arrays under a single node?

Tags: .net, json.net

When I call JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode with a JSON string that contains an array like this:

```
{"Name":"Brian","Wife":{"Name":"Christine"},"Children":[{"Name":"Kiara"},{"Name":"Abrian"},{"Name":"Brooke"}]}
```

I get XML that looks like this:

```
<Root>
  <Name>Brian</Name>
  <Wife>
    <Name>Christine</Name>
  </Wife>
  <Children>
    <Name>Kiara</Name>
  </Children>
  <Children>
    <Name>Abrian</Name>
  </Children>
  <Children>
    <Name>Brooke</Name>
  </Children>
</Root>
```

What I want is something that looks like this:

```
<Root>
  <Name>Brian</Name>
  <Wife>
    <Name>Christine</Name>
  </Wife>
  <Children>
    <Child>
      <Name>Kiara</Name>
    </Child>
    <Child>
      <Name>Abrian</Name>
    </Child>
    <Child>
      <Name>Brooke</Name>
    </Child>
  </Children>
</Root>
```

To make this more complex, I'm trying to do this in framework code, so I don't really know what the data is that's coming in, which means that I have no idea what to call the child element, but perhaps just one problem at a time :).

Comment: `I don't really know what the data is that's coming in` If you don't know it, how do you expect such an output? what is the algorithm? If you write the rules, then, we may try to answer it.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, right now I don't really care what it is called, I just want the array to serialize under a single node, I'll deal with the naming issue separately.

Comment: So you say, the answer should make a semantic analysis and guess that `Children` object should have sub objects `Child`. Data-Datum, Media-Medium and all similar stuff? **Just write your rules**

Comment: You cannot do what you want by using `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode`. That is it's default behavior. Check [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm). To achieve what you want you can deserialize the `json` string to strongly typed classes and then serialize to `xml` or use built in `LINQ to JSON` functionality in `JSON.NET` library. You will have more control with one of these approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following custom XmlNodeConverter will serialize arrays under a single node, with each array element assigned a specified name. Given you don't know the incoming data, you could opt for a generic name like "Element", in which case your example json would translate to:

```
<Children>
   <Element>
      <Name>Christine</Name>
   </Element>
   <Element>
      <Name>Kiara</Name>
   </Element>
</Children>
```

The custom XmlNodeConverter:

```
public class SingleArrayNodeXmlConverter : XmlNodeConverter
{
    public string ArrayElementName { get; set; }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JObject.Load(reader);
        InjectArrayElements(token, ArrayElementName);
        var innerReader = token.CreateReader();
        innerReader.Read();
        return base.ReadJson(innerReader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }

    private static void InjectArrayElements(JToken token, string elementName)
    {
        foreach (var childToken in token)
        {
            InjectArrayElements(childToken, elementName);
        }
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            var arrayHolder = new JObject { { elementName, token } };
            token.Replace(arrayHolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var converter = new SingleArrayNodeXmlConverter
{
    DeserializeRootElementName = "Root",
    WriteArrayAttribute = false,
    ArrayElementName = "Element"
};
return (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(XmlDocument), converter);
```

This solution is obviously a compromise, but in our situation even a generic array element is better than repeating the array node itself.

Answer (score -2):

```
{"Name":"Brian","Wife":{"Name":"Christine"},"Children":["Child":{"Name":"Kiara"},"Child":{"Name":"Abrian"},"Child":{"Name":"Brooke"}]}
```